# Find similarities using scatterplot in R with 4 continuous variables and 1 class variable

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
V1    V2    V3   V4   V5
5.1   3.0   1.4  0.2  1
4.4   1.0   1.1  0.4  1
4.7   5.0   3.6  0.3  2
1.1   4.2   2.4  1.2  2
4.4   1.0   1.1  4.4  3
4.7   3.9   4.6  2.3  3
```

I need to find which 2 class(column V5) are similar using only scatterplot.

Please advice how can i plot this. I know how to do with only 2 variables but here i have 4 variables with 1 class variable

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by similar? If you want to explore all possible combinations of scatterplots try `pairs(df)`, where `df` if the name of your dataframe. More info about pairs [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/pairs.html)

Comment: I want to find with 2 classes are similar out of the 3 classes given in the dataset

Comment: "similar" (to my knowledge) is no expression with a formal definition (in contrast to "median" or "distribution"). So I guess, @thepule was asking whether you mean that the classes are optically (seen i a scatterplot) similar, or something else.

Comment: optically seen similar

Comment: I am still not clear about what you are asking. But may be this can help if you are asking only about visual interpretation from scatterplot: `ggplot(dat, aes(x=V1, y=V2, color=V5,size=V3,alpha=V4)) + geom_point()`